# GitHub for Windows with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013, github-for-windows

I installed VS and GitHub for Windows. Now, I clone reporisotries using VS and then use GitHub for Windows for shell prompt etc.

On VS however, it notifies that I need to install 3rd-party tools for GitHub command prompt support. On "Changes" screen in Team Explorer, if I open command prompt (under Actions) type "git", it doesn't recognize the command.

If I open the 3rd-party tools link and install, it installs another full-fledged git software and then let me use the command prompt.

Is there a way to integrate GitHub for Windows with VS, such that we don't require a duplicate git installation?

Comment: GitHub installs the tools privately in the %AppData% folders and doesn't really register them. Which is Why Visual Studio can't find them. I just install a second version of git side-by-side. You might be able to install git over the location that GitHub for Windows uses?

Comment: @jessehouwing It doesn't sound like a good idea to install another git distribution over the GitHub for Windows installation. I expect a lot of conflicts if they are not completely the same.

Comment: Hence might. I don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. I could not find a way to get the GitHub Desktop (formerly GitHub for Windows) application to work with Visual Studio (or the Windows Command Prompt in general).

So the way I solved this is that I installed [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads). I recommend installing it with administrator rights, that way it gets installed to the Program Files folder by default. It's not necessary though, if installed normally, it gets installed to a subfolder in the user's AppData folder by default. If you select the proper options during install (it's very straightforward, just read the description of the available options), it will be possible to use it from Visual Studio (and the Windows Command Prompt). Once you have that, having the GitHub Desktop application and its shell isn't necessary anymore, as you can do everything from within Visual Studio. You can browse your repositories, create new branches, open a Command Prompt and use git within it, etc.